# Open windows photo gallery from python

Tags: python, windows

I want the end of a python script to open windows photo gallery from python

I try:

```
os.system("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Live\\Photo Gallery\\WLXPhotoGallery.exe");
```

I get:

```
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

any ideas how to get this one sorted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `os.system()`. Use the [`subprocess` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system) instead:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Live\\Photo Gallery\\WLXPhotoGallery.exe")
```

Answer (score 5):

As Martijn Pieters points out, you really should use `subprocess`. However, if you are really curious as to why your call didn't work, it's because calling `os.system("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Live\\Photo Gallery\\WLXPhotoGallery.exe");` is equivalent to typing this on the command line: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Photo Gallery\WLXPhotoGallery.exe`.
See those spaces in the file path? The windows shell sees each space-separated string as a separate command/argument. Therefore, it tries to execute the program `C:\Program` with the arguments `Files`, `(x86)\Windows`, `Live\Photo`, `Gallery\WLXPhotoGallery.exe`. Of course, since there's no program on your computer at `C:\Program`, this borks.

If, for whatever reason, you really REALLY want to go with `os.system`, you should think about how you would execute the command on the command line itself. To execute this on the command line, you'd type `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Photo Gallery\WLXPhotoGallery.exe"` (the quotes escape the spaces). In order to translate this into your `os.system` call, you should do this:

```
os.system('"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Live\\Photo Gallery\\WLXPhotoGallery.exe"');
```

Really though, you should use `subprocess`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to imbed double quotes in your string. I'm not a python dude, but in C# you would need your string to be: "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Live\\Photo Gallery\\WLXPhotoGallery.exe\"", so Windows can deal with the spaces in there.